# Ran out of quests

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have 9 Imperial levels, tons of inventory as I kept them producing,  and always sent anyone who wanted to go to a residential level down to speed up production. Finished the last quest, and now it says that there are no more quests. That is ridiculous, I should not run out of quests before I have constructed all the Imperial levels. I was enjoying the cash bonus for each complete quest (last one netted me 209k in coin). Without these imperial quests,  half of the gameplay is gone, and I have no reason to build more imperial levels.

Please tell me this is a bug

Comment: I have the same issue.  Emperor just told me to build 2 more Imperial levels, built the first one hoping it would reinvigorate Darth Vader to offer more quests, but alas, still nothing.  It ran out when I had 9 Imperial levels too.

Answer (score 4):

Tiny Death Star is a sandbox game, just like the original Tiny Tower. The addition of the questing system is there just to help you get started, like a hand holding exercise. If explains the game to you and gives you some startup cash.

The real content of the game is building your tiny death star up as high as you can make it, with really no limit. Your not out of content because your out of quests, since the original tiny tower had no quests and still had good staying power. The real gameplay is managing inventory, assigning bitizens and of course, adding levels.

Comment: But there is no incentive to build any items in the Imperial Levels anymore,  and  one VIP is totally useless,  and what Good is a supply officer and the inventory I create on the Imperial levels can't be used for Anything.  Not to mention the thousands I wasted summoning supply officers to build up inventory for future quests.  To me, without these quests, half my tower is useless. So is all my imperial inventory I built up. I feel like I wasted a lot off resources, and that the game isn't as interesting without these imperial quests.

Comment: @Gerard don't forget that the game has features yet to be added

Comment: How hard would it be to generate more random quests, combining several inventory items? I am about a week in and already completed the quests,  just seems silly to run out, and as I said, Feels like half the game is now missing and imperial levels are pointless. I have no need to build them or send anyone down.   The quests have me something to do while selling inventory, now I have nothing.

Comment: @Gerard I had nearly the same experience, and it was very disheartening to get the flow going for those levels and all of a sudden have the floor drop out.  The feature is so obvious, I'm sure it's in production.  Please just go leave a review in iTunes so the developers know that it's important.  Has anyone found a true NimbleBit forum to leave feedback?

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me with 9 levels.  @Resorath is talking about the missions, which actually do continue.  The Imperial quests are different.  The missions teach you the game in the beginning and get you on the right track.  They have ridiculously low rewards later in the game though.  The imperial quests had quite substantial rewards towards the end.  The only thing I can think is that they are going to add more in an update.

Comment: The Emperor is telling me to build an Imperial level for 400 credits but it's going to cost me 470k credits and probably 24 hours.  And there's no more quests.  I'll build more Imperial Levels when my other levels are done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have had the same issue.  I don't think it's specifically a bug.  But, there is a continued value to building the Imperial Levels, because many of them have unlock-able scene associated with them.  So, at least there is that benefit.