# Is it worth stock piling every imperial floor item available?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've been creating imperial items non stop. I currently have 11 imperial levels and have noticed the imperial objectives have lately not been using some of the early stage imperial floor items I've been stock piling.

These items include Rebel Secrets and Security Codes. I currently have over 35 of each, and I'm just wondering if later objectives even use these? I've gone through 10-15 objectives without using them so far. I've also noticed 2 other items that I have been using a little bit but just wondering if I should stop collecting them at a certain point to save money as I always spend the 1000 coins to collect imperial items as it pays off huge in the long run.

These items are Salvage at 23, and Star Maps at 18. Also if you know when to stop stock piling other items this information would be helpful as well. Lastly if this helps at all I currently need 5 Lieutenants 6 battle plans and 7 defense grids for a reward of $71,910. I don't know if this information will even help you help me as I'm unaware if the Imperial objectives are the same or even similar between one another.

Comment: please consider editing this question. There is way too much information in here for a simple question. We don't need all of the stock levels of the items. They are the same in everyone's game.

Comment: Please don't edit your question if you find an answer.  Consider self-answering, or linking to the relevant question in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, stock piling helps with the imperial quests going forward. When you complete a quest, the next one may ask for an item that you have already stocked. So, in general, you will likely get paid back for those items you paid credits to generate.  That said, you will do better in the long run building floors that generate credits as a means to make credits. And, if you are diverting too many credits to your inventory you will make less money over time.

In answer to the other portion of your question, many of the lesser items will re-appear in later quests, just in large quantities.

[image]

Comment: Any source on that?

Comment: Doesn't really require a source. Basically, every time you finish a quest, another one is around the corner requesting a new list of those items. So, stock piling will net you credits. But, as the quests get larger say costing you 30K credits to make 50K credits, your net gain is less than what I make in a few minutes off my floors (currently about 1000 creds a minute).  Granted some quests have big payoffs, but many do not.

Comment: I'm asking, because the asker clearly has gotten a different experience (these low-tier stocked items aren't used all that much), and there's still the previous indication that there might still be *an* end to the missions (just further out than [the last time](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142937/)), in which case the stockpiled items might be ultimately useless.

Comment: I will add that with 69 levels, the wait time for building new levels and stocking some levels makes it frustrating and so, at times I will happily do these quests as a way to rapidly generate credits.

Comment: Good point. But, last time when I stockpiled, and they added more quests, I got a large infusion of credits, but then wound up back to the wait and build style. I'm basically saying it's sort of equivocal. If you get a lot of supply officers, and stock like, great. Spending creds doesn't seem as good long term. (Not that I don't do it anyway …). Also, the low tiered ones come back in other quests. I've had to generate 20 rebel secrets for example.

Comment: But what happens when the quests run out?

Comment: If history is a teacher, they will make more for a future update. And, if they run out, just do what I did. Only stockpile using the supply officers that continue to come.

Comment: I've added a photo illustrating my point.  25 Security codes!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that spending any credits to get the Supply Officer to stockpile is generally not worth it if your credits can be better spent on level building since you can generate more credits that way. I have noticed that the quest rewards have reduced dramatically as you go on - I think mine peaked at just under 200,000, and now it's 70,000. I'd rather stockpile credit for future content updates as doing the quest gives no additional reward other than more credit.

Comment: There are quests that give you more than 200,000 credits, but I agree that the time/credit investments are not quite worth it until you've built as many levels as you can.